# How do I correct camera angle and something like homography

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, camera, affinetransform, homography

I need to transform some image planes to make them parallel to the camera lens. Now the images are inclined. I have looked into homography and affine transformation and got some idea. Just wanted to know if there are any solutions for that while I search my own.
[image]

Any suggestion in matlab or python is preferred.
Thanks